# Phonegap MacOSX won't run - 4.4.2 (API 19) not listed

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I've checked for a possible duplicate around here / google but didn't find any.

I have just downloaded the latest android-sdk version 23.0.2. After realoading the Android SDK Manager packaged I still cannot list / download 4.4.2 (API 19) package.

I am tryind to run a phonegap project on Eclipse/Android but it won't load it. Has anyone ever solved this problem? Any ideas?

Here's the log. Also check the image below. Thanks!

```
MacBook-henriquesv:iRezo henriquesv2$ phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...

/Users/henriquesv2/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.
at /Users/henriquesv2/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:80:29
at _fulfilled (/Users/henriquesv2/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/henriquesv2/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/henriquesv2/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
at /Users/henriquesv2/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/Users/henriquesv2/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
{ [Error: /Users/henriquesv2/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }
   [error] /Users/henriquesv2/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After hours searching for an answer I found a solution that was never posted.
I've seen  many people saying that running Android SDK Manager as Administrator on Windows did the trick.
So I decided to do "the same as root on Mac OSX! That solved the question.
Simple like this:

```
sudo /Users/henriquesv2/Desenvolvimento/adt-android-mac/sdk/tools/android
```

Now I can see many other packages that were not listed before.
I hope it can help anybody else. =)